# Excel 2012 Pivot Table Displayed Data

Tags: excel, pivot

I am trying to make a simple bug viewer with Excel. I think I need a pivot table for this.

I have attached a screen shot of what I have got so far. What I would like, is instead of the 'Count of x' columns, is the actual data to be displayed.

[image: Excel 2012 Pivot Table Bug Viewer]

My data table is formatted as follows:

[image: Excel 2012 Sample Data]

Thank you very much,

Richard Hughes

Comment: Providing an example data table would be useful. Can you also show us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Julian: I have edited my post to add some sample data.

Comment: I am trying to display the bugs by their ids. So in the pivot table, I would like the little + expander by the ids, and then all of the bugs where the 'Parent Id' matches, should display in the expanded section

Comment: At the moment, the bugs display a count of the data, for instance 'Count of Item'- I would like the actual text displayed there instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the actual text displayed in those columns. The columns show aggregated data. You can have counts and sums, averages, etc.

I *think* that what you want is the "classic" pivot table view. Go into the pivot table options, Display tab and select "Classic Pivottable Layout".

Then add the data you want to see as "Row Labels" not Values. You might want to keep a count of ID as a value. Is that better?

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I want, and is good enough for my purposes at the moment. I'll post back if I need anything else. Thanks again!